# how does .bss segment allocates and deallocates the memory for the C program?

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, memory-layout

I am trying to understand the logic behind the .bss memory allocation and deallocation

I have few cases which I have tried to understand the same.

I concluded that it is incrementing in the chunks of 8 bytes if I declare any variable in the global scope of the code because of the linker script of mine is having the alignment of 8 bytes

but when I define the variable inside the same scope it is deallocating the memory from the .bss

but exactly what is the logical calculations behind the deallocation is which I do not understand?

case1 :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
int b;

int main(void){
        return 0;
}
```

this code snippet generates the below sizes for the different segments

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1418     544      16    1978     7ba a.out
```

now if I initialize one int variable like this

case 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1;
int b;

int main(void){
        return 0;
}
```

this gives me the following size table

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1418     548      12    1978     7ba a.out
```

now if I initialize one char before the int variable like this

case 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a = 1;
int b;

int main(void){
        return 0;
}
```

it is showing

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1418     545      12    1978     7ba a.out
```

this is the nm -n output specifically for the case 3

```
0000000000004000 D __data_start
0000000000004000 W data_start
0000000000004008 D __dso_handle
0000000000004010 D a
0000000000004011 B __bss_start
0000000000004011 D _edata
0000000000004014 b completed.8060
0000000000004018 D __TMC_END__
0000000000004018 B b
0000000000004020 B _end
```

now if I initialize one int variable like this

case 4:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1;
char b;

int main(void){
        return 0;
}
```

it is showing

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1418     548      4    1978     7ba a.out
```

now if I initialize one int variable like this

case 5:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a = 1;
char b;

int main(void){
        return 0;
}
```

it is showing

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1418     545      7    1978     7ba a.out
```

anyone please help me to understand this ?

Comment: Which part of your observations is unclear?

Comment: Lets take case 1 and 2: You see that the data section increases by `4` (the size of an `int`) while the BSS decreases by `4`? That should be pretty obvious. As for the rest, it's probably alignment related, so the variables end up on nice "even" addresses in memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
in the case 3 when I defined char a = 1; it is showing .bss = 7 but when I declared int b; in the same code, .bss should have 15 but no!! it is having 12. this is bit unclear.

Comment: @Yunnosch the memory deallocation part of the .bss is which I can not understand clearly

Comment: You really have to find the standard linker script used by your linker, to see what it really does and how it aligns the sections.

Comment: "in the case 3 when I defined char a = 1; it is showing .bss = 7" Um, no. In case 3 it shows bss size of 12. The 7 only appears in your case 5. Can you double check that the values given in the different cases in your question match what you observe? And that the shown code matches the code your observations are based on? I ask, because while I cannot explain all the way to case 5. I do not yet have problems with case 3, assuming case 1 as "foundation/offset".

Comment: I suggest running `nm -n a.out` to see where things end up in memory.

Comment: What are the numbers if you have no variables at all?

Comment: @Yunnosch, in the case 3 there is the calculation of 12 for .bss is unclear. I mean how did it allocates 12 to .bss

Comment: @Yunnosch, if there is no variable at all in my code the size of .bss is 8

Comment: Please [edit] to bring additional info.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes I have checked and I have edited my question to put the output of this command. there are no exact 12 bytes in between the bssStart and bss end. could you please make me understand how the size command shows 12 for .bss ? I am not getting it

Comment: @Yunnosch, yes I have edited my question and added the output of nm -n to make it more clear.

Comment: There is a disagreement between the `nm -n a.out` output for case 3 and the variable names. Did you rename `a` to `c`?

Comment: @IanAbbott yes, I had renamed it, I edited that. now you can look into it

Comment: For case 3, the difference between `_end` and `__bss_start` is 15, but that includes 3 bytes of padding between `__bss_start` and `completed.8060`. I guess the tool (GNU 'size') you use to display the size of the `bss` manages to ignore the padding at the start. `b` will be 4 bytes long, so I'm not sure why there is an additional 4 bytes between the end of `b` and `_end`. I guess it must be aligning `_end` to an 8-byte boundary for some reason.

Comment: @IanAbbott how is the difference between __bss_start and _end is 15? it is 4011-4020. this is 9. the calculation of 12 is still unclear

Comment: The nm -n offsets are hexadecimal, so the difference between 4011 and 4020 is F (hex), i.e. 15 (dec).

Answer (score 1):

Symbols of a given type have a natural alignment that the linker must honor (e.g. `int` must be 4 byte aligned). Within a given section (e.g. `.bss`), the linker has some leeway to reorder the symbols so that the alignment of a given symbol doesn't cause excess padding. If we have:

```
char a;
int b;
```

Without the reordering, the load map would look like:

```
0000 a
0004 b
```

And, the section length would be 8.

With reordering:

```
0000 b
0000 a
```

And, the section length would be 5

Note that the size of the sections is *aligned* upward to some multiple (usually 8 bytes). So, for example, if a section has only 1 byte of data, the section size will be reported as 8.

But, there are exceptions.

One of the ways to see this more clearly is to simplify the data:

1. We can elide any libraries or startup code to reduce the executable size.
2. We can use addresses relative to the start of the *first* data section (e.g. start of `.data`)
3. Combine results from all cases into a single table

I've created a [perl] script to do that. It has your original test cases and some additional ones.

Of particular note is case 6 ...

Below is the output of the script. The final table [and discussion] is in the **FINAL** section below.

---

**Case 1:**

Source:

```
int a;
int b;
int _start(void) { return 0; }
```

Command: `nm -n xfile`

```
0000 B b
0000 B __bss_start
0000 B _edata
0004 B a
0008 B _end
```

Command: `size xfile`

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     50       0       8      58      3a xfile
```

---

**Case 2:**

Source:

```
int a = 1;
int b;
int _start(void) { return 0; }
```

Command: `nm -n xfile`

```
0000 D a
0004 B b
0004 B __bss_start
0004 D _edata
0008 B _end
```

Command: `size xfile`

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     50       4       4      58      3a xfile
```

---

**Case 3:**

Source:

```
char a = 1;
int b;
int _start(void) { return 0; }
```

Command: `nm -n xfile`

```
0000 D a
0001 B __bss_start
0001 D _edata
0004 B b
0008 B _end
```

Command: `size xfile`

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     50       1       4      55      37 xfile
```

---

**Case 4:**

Source:

```
int a = 1;
char b;
int _start(void) { return 0; }
```

Command: `nm -n xfile`

```
0000 D a
0004 B b
0004 B __bss_start
0004 D _edata
0008 B _end
```

Command: `size xfile`

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     50       4       4      58      3a xfile
```

---

**Case 5:**

Source:

```
char a = 1;
char b;
int _start(void) { return 0; }
```

Command: `nm -n xfile`

```
0000 D a
0001 B b
0001 B __bss_start
0001 D _edata
0008 B _end
```

Command: `size xfile`

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     50       1       7      58      3a xfile
```

---

**Case 6:**

Source:

```
char a;
int b;
char c = 1;
int d = 1;
int _start(void) { return 0; }
```

Command: `nm -n xfile`

```
0000 D d
0004 D c
0005 B __bss_start
0005 D _edata
0008 B b
000C B a
0010 B _end
```

Command: `size xfile`

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     50       5       8      63      3f xfile
```

---

**FINAL:**

```
CASE    DATA    BSS     DEFS
1       0       8       int a; int b;
                        00/B/b 00/B/__bss_start 00/B/_edata 04/B/a 08/B/_end
2       4       4       int a = 1; int b;
                        00/D/a 04/B/b 04/B/__bss_start 04/D/_edata 08/B/_end
3       1       4       char a = 1; int b;
                        00/D/a 01/B/__bss_start 01/D/_edata 04/B/b 08/B/_end
4       4       4       int a = 1; char b;
                        00/D/a 04/B/b 04/B/__bss_start 04/D/_edata 08/B/_end
5       1       7       char a = 1; char b;
                        00/D/a 01/B/b 01/B/__bss_start 01/D/_edata 08/B/_end
6       5       8       char a; int b; char c = 1; int d = 1;
                        00/D/d 04/D/c 05/B/__bss_start 05/D/_edata 08/B/b 0C/B/a 10/B/_end
```

Note that in case 6, the `.data` length is 5. And, the starting address of `.bss` is [also] 5. But, the lowest `.bss` address actually *used* is 8 (for `b`)

---

Here is the script source:

````
#!/usr/bin/perl
# bssgen -- generate .bss data
#
# options:
#   "-c" -- use .o instead of executable
#   "-O" -- optimzation level (DEFAULT: 2)
#   "-v" -- output to stdout (DEFAULT: off)

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    $opt_c = 0;
    $opt_O = 2;

    $pubfile = "bssgen.txt";
    printf("output to %s\n",$pubfile);
    $xfpub = xfopen(">$pubfile","master");

    optget(\@argv,
        ["c",1],
        ["n",1],
        ["O",1]);

    my($xfsrc) = "bssgen::DATA";
    $xfsrc = \*$xfsrc;

    while ($bf = <$xfsrc>) {
        chomp($bf);

        if ($bf =~ /^\s*$/) {
            dotest();
        }
        else {
            push(@defs,$bf);
        }
    }

    dotest()
        if (@defs > 0);

    final();

    $xfpub = xfclose($xfpub);
}

sub final
{

    prtsct("FINAL:");

    prtsep();

    @prtcol_tabs = (0,8,16,24);

    prtcol("%s","CASE");
    prtcol("%s","DATA");
    prtcol("%s","BSS");
    prtcol("%s","DEFS");
    prtcol();

    $caseno = 0;
    foreach $tst (@tstlist) {
        ++$caseno;

        prtcol("%d",$caseno);
        prtcol("%d",$tst->{tst_data});
        prtcol("%d",$tst->{tst_bss});
        prtcol("%s",$tst->{tst_defs});
        prtcol();

        prtcol("%s");
        prtcol("%s");
        prtcol("%s");

        my($buf);
        my($nmlhs) = $tst->{tst_nm};
        my($base);
        foreach $nm (@$nmlhs) {
            $buf .= " "
                if (defined($buf));
            $buf .= sprintf("%2.2X/%s/%s",
                $nm->{addr},$nm->{typ},$nm->{sym});
        }
        prtcol("%s",$buf);
        prtcol();
    }

    prtsep();
}

sub dotest
{

    prtsct("Case %d:",++$caseno);

    my($root) = "xfile";
    my($sfile) = $root . ".c";
    my($ofile) = $root . ".o";
    my($xfile) = $root;
    my($run) = $root;

    local($xfdst) = xfopen(">$sfile","dotest/sfile");

    prtpub("Source:\n");
    prtsep();
    foreach $bf (@defs) {
        prtcode("%s\n",$bf);
    }
    prtcode("int %s(void) { return 0; }\n",$opt_c ? "main" : "_start");
    prtsep();

    $xfdst = xfclose($xfdst);

    my(@cflags);
    push(@cflags,"-O")
        if ($opt_O);
    push(@cflags,"-c");
    doexec("cc",@cflags,$sfile);

    unless ($opt_c) {
        doexec("ld","-o",$xfile,$ofile);
        $run = $xfile;
    }
    else {
        $run = $ofile;
    }

    my(@nm);
    push(@nm,"-n");
    @nmrhs = grab(0,"nm",@nm,$run);
    my($base);
    my(@nmlhs);
    prtsep();
    foreach $nm (@nmrhs) {
        chomp($nm);

        my($addr,$typ,$sym) = split(" ",$nm);
        next if ($typ eq "T");

        $addr = hex("0x$addr");
        $base //= $addr;

        $nm = {};
        $nm->{addr} = $addr - $base;
        $nm->{typ} = $typ;
        $nm->{sym} = $sym;

        prtpub("%4.4X %s %s\n",$nm->{addr},$nm->{typ},$nm->{sym});

        push(@nmlhs,$nm);
    }
    prtsep();

    my(@siz) = grab(1,"size",$run);
    my($txt,$data,$bss) = split(" ",$siz[1]);

    my($tst) = {};
    $tst->{tst_defs} = join(" ",@defs);
    $tst->{tst_data} = $data + 0;
    $tst->{tst_bss} = $bss + 0;;
    $tst->{tst_nm} = \@nmlhs;
    push(@tstlist,$tst);

    unless ($opt_k) {
        unlink($sfile);
        unlink($ofile);
        unlink($xfile);
    }

    undef(@defs);
}

sub xfopen
{
    my($file,$who) = @_;
    my($xf);

    open($xf,$file) or
        die("xfopen: unable to open '$file' -- $!\n");

    $xf;
}

sub xfclose
{
    my($xf) = @_;

    close($xf);
    undef($xf);

    $xf;
}

sub grab
{
    my($vflg,@argv) = @_;
    my($cmd,@cmd);

    $cmd = $argv[0];

    prtpub("\n");
    $cmd = join(" ",@argv);
    prtpub("Command: `%s`\n",$cmd);

    @cmd = (`$cmd`);

    prtsep()
        if ($vflg);
    foreach $cmd (@cmd) {
        chomp($cmd);
        prtpub("%s\n",$cmd)
            if ($vflg);
    }
    prtsep()
        if ($vflg);

    @cmd;
}

sub doexec
{

    $_ = join(" ",@_);
    system($_);

    $_ = $? >> 8;
    exit($_) if ($_);
}

sub prtsct
{
    my($fmt,$arg) = @_;

    prtpub("\n");
    prtpub("%s\n","-" x 8);

    $fmt = "**" . $fmt . "**\n";

    prtpub($fmt,$arg);

    prtpub("\n");
}

sub prtsep
{

    prtpub("```\n");
}

sub prtcol
{
    my($fmt,$val) = @_;
    my($tabto);

    {
        unless (defined($fmt)) {
            prtpub("%s\n",$prtcol_buf);
            undef($prtcol_buf);
            undef($prtcol_idx);
            last;
        }

        $tabto = $prtcol_tabs[$prtcol_idx++];
        while (length($prtcol_buf) < $tabto) {
            $prtcol_buf .= " ";
        }

        $fmt = sprintf($fmt,$val);
        $prtcol_buf .= $fmt;
    }
}

sub prtpub
{
    my($fmt);

    $fmt = shift(@_);
    printf($xfpub $fmt,@_);
    printf($fmt,@_)
        if ($opt_v);
}

sub prtcode
{
    my($fmt);

    $fmt = shift(@_);
    printf($xfdst $fmt,@_);
    prtpub($fmt,@_);
}

sub optget
{
    my($argv,@opts) = @_;
    my($arg,$opt);
    my($sym,$val);

    @opts = sort({ $b->[0] cmp $a->[0]} @opts);

    while (@$argv > 0) {
        $arg = $argv->[0];
        last unless ($arg =~ s/^-//);

        shift(@$argv);

        foreach $opt (@opts) {
            my($sym,$dft) = @$opt;

            if ($arg =~ /^$sym(.*)$/) {
                $val = $1;

                {
                    last if ($val =~ s/^=//);
                    last if ($val ne "");
                    $val = $dft;
                }

                ${"opt_" . $sym} = $val;

                last;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach $opt (@opts) {
        my($sym,$dft) = @$opt;
        $sym = "opt_" . $sym;
        ###printf("optget: DEBUG_CAE %s %s\n",$sym,$$sym);
    }
}

package bssgen;
__DATA__
int a;
int b;

int a = 1;
int b;

char a = 1;
int b;

int a = 1;
char b;

char a = 1;
char b;

char a;
int b;
char c = 1;
int d = 1;
````

Comment: in the case 3 of this answer, there are more than 4 bytes in between the bss_start and bss_end in the output of nm -n command. but the size command output showing 4 for the .bss

Comment: I I also have  edited my question, specifically for case 3, I have added the output of nm -n for it. could you please help me to understand the same ?